# Statusbar color on iPad with iOS6

Tags: ios6, uicolor, ipad, uistatusbar

I noticed that statusbar tint properties is selectable only in iPhone project summary, but I would like to tint my status bar on an iPad app, is it possible to do? I can't find any method

Answer (score 1):

No, the iPad status bar will always be black.
It is stated in the [`UIApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation section of [`UIStatusBarStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW19):

> **Special Considerations**
>
> On iPad devices, the UIStatusBarStyleDefault
>   and UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent styles default to the
>   UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this quote from iOS 6 release notes:

> It is now possible to set status bar tint parameters in your app’s Info.plist file. You might do this to ensure that the status bar color matches your app’s navigation bar color during startup. To set the status bar tint, add the UIStatusBarTintParameters key to your Info.plist file. The value of this key is a dictionary with the appropriate values describing the navigation bar your app has at startup. Inside the dictionary should be the UINavigationBar key, which has a value that is also a dictionary. That dictionary contains the initial navigation bar’s style (with the Style key) and indicates whether it is translucent (with the Translucent key).